# Reading STDOUT and STDERR of external command with no wait

Tags: perl

I would like to execute external command `rtmpdump` and read it's `STDOUT` and `STDERR` separately, but not to wait till such command ends, but read its partial outputs in bulks, when available...

What is a safe way to do it in Perl?

---

This is a code I have that works "per-line" basis:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Symbol;
use IPC::Open3;
use IO::Select;

sub execute {
  my($cmd) = @_;
  print "[COMMAND]: $cmd\n";
  my $pid = open3(my $in, my $out, my $err = gensym(), $cmd);
  print "[PID]: $pid\n";
  my $sel = new IO::Select;
  $sel->add($out, $err);
  while(my @fhs = $sel->can_read) {
    foreach my $fh (@fhs) {
      my $line = <$fh>;
      unless(defined $line) {
        $sel->remove($fh);
        next;
      }
      if($fh == $out) {
        print "[OUTPUT]: $line";
      } elsif($fh == $err) {
        print "[ERROR] : $line";
      } else {
        die "[ERROR]: This should never execute!";
      }
    }
  }
  waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

But the above code works in text mode only, I believe. To use `rtmpdump` as a command, I need to collect partial outputs in binary mode, so do not read `STDOUT` line-by-line as it is in the above code.

Binary output of STDOUT should be stored in variable, not printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using blocking functions (e.g. `readline` aka `<>`, `read`, etc) inside a `select` loop defies the use of `select`.

```
$sel->add($out, $err);

my %bufs;
while ($sel->count) {
   for my $fh ($sel->can_read) {
      my $rv = sysread($fh, $bufs{$fh}, 128*1024, length($bufs{$fh}));

      if (!defined($rv)) {
         # Error
         die $! ;
      }

      if (!$rv) {
         # Eof
         $sel->remove($fh);
         next;
      }        

      if ($fh == $err) {
         while ($bufs{$err} =~ s/^(.*\n)//) {
            print "[ERROR] $1";
         }
      }
   }
}

print "[ERROR] $bufs{$err}\n" if length($bufs{$err});

waitpid($pid, 0);

... do something with $bufs{$out} ...
```

But it would be much simpler to use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun).

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my ($out_buf, $err_buf);
run [ 'sh', '-c', $cmd ],
   '>', \$out_buf, 
   '2>', sub {
      $err_buf .= $_[0];
      while ($err_buf =~ s/^(.*\n)//) {
         print "[ERROR] $1";
      }
   };

print "[ERROR] $err_buf\n" if length($err_buf);

... do something with $out_buf ...
```

Comment: I should clarify one issue: Besides of storing STDOUT data to variable I need to be able to process those partial data, whenever are available. Other words, some function should be call with new STDOUT data each time when they are available.

Comment: @Ωmega replace `\$out_buf` with sub ref

Comment: Like @mpapec said, follow the example of STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a POSIX system, try using [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod).  This is exactly the sort of problem it is designed to solve, and it also simplifies the task of sending keystrokes to the spawned process.

Comment: I am confused - can you explain why Expect.pm would not solve your problem?  Or are you specifically wanting to create a "from-scratch" solution without using existing libraries?